# Remote copy file to same directory to all hostnames

Tags: linux, bash, copy, host, hostname

Am trying to write a distribute script to copy a file to the named hostname from the host file and goes into the same directory.

For example:

```
dist -hostname1 file.txt
dist -all file.txt
```

The -all should be able to distribute to all the hostnames on the network.

I know this can probably be done with a rcp command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scp` to do this. It uses `ssh` to securely copy the file. Nowadays `rcp` is just an alias for the `scp` command.

user is the login on the remote machine.

**Copy file to host in /file-dest-dir**

```
scp file.txt user@host:/file-dest-dir
```

**A script to copy to a number of hosts:**

```
file=$1
hosts="host1 host2 host3"
for host in $hosts
do
     scp "$1" user@${host}:
done
```

**Get hosts from /etc/hosts**

```
hosts=$(awk '!/^#/ {print $2}' /etc/hosts)
for host in $hosts
do
     scp "$1" user@${host}:
done
```

Comment: How do i get it to do this to all the hosts available on the network.

For example i call another script maybe called "dist" where i can just put a command like allhosts and then the file i want to copy

Comment: Thanks for this i was thinking this for loop but wanted a way to actually grab the hostnames from the hosts file rather than setting the variable manually as i have about 200 hosts on the network

Comment: Is there a way of doing what i have asked in the above comment? Also can i use the for loop to just send to one host if i dont want to send it to multiple hosts.

Comment: Yes of course. If you wanted to loop through all your hosts you would have to set up SSH keys to all the hosts. Otherwise you would be prompted for the user's password for each copy.

Comment: In the "hosts=" variable do i have to manually enter all the avaiable hosts here? Is there a way to grab all the hostnames on the network from the hosts file through another script?
If i used a rcp for this instead would it ask for the user's password for each copy?

Comment: I've added a simple example. I don't think `rcp` in it's original form still exists. As mentioned `rcp` nowadays on linux is just an alias of `scp`.

Comment: Thats great exactly what i need didnt realise though you have to login each time for a secure copy :/

Comment: You *don't* once you have setup your SSH environment suitably.